# Windows are up-scaled on secondary monitor in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and a TV connected to my video card (AMD R7 260x)

```
Monitor 2 (primary): 1920x1080, DVI
extends to
Monitor 1: 1920x1080, VGA
cloned to
Television: 1920x1080 HDMI
```

[image: Resolution Settings]

---

The problem is, the image on the secondary monitor and TV is stretched, as if they were a different resolution. As seen with these chrome instances, they should be the same size. Moving a window from one monitor to another changes its size, if I move the big chrome instance to the left monitor, at some point when crossing the edge it will instantly change to the normal version.

[image: Comparison]

It fixes itself when I change the resolution to something else then change it back to 1920x1080. But it goes back to the ugly mode after reboot.

---

What I tried:

- Reinstalling Video Driver
- Reinstalling Windows
- Change scaling (now it's set to be the same on all displays, but it doesn't have any effect)

I don't even know if it's a Windows issue or a Video card driver issue.

Has anyone had this issue before? I don't know where to turn to, it's very annoying to have to change resolution after every reboot.

Comment: Have you looked around in the Catalyst Control Center? There may be some advanced options which are not available in the Windows Display Settings

Comment: This is probably not related but when I used my HD 7870 there was an underscan issue which I had to hunt down myself. This post describes it: http://superuser.com/a/64264/259665

Comment: Yes, I looked there too, I'm not saying there aren't any, but I didn't even find options for scaling windows. I saw the scaling options too for the whole image, but that seems to be a different thing.