# Windows 8.1 and a Sharp Aquos

Tags: laptop, display, tv, duplicate

I just bought a new Laptop with Windows 8.1 on it. My previous laptop had Windows 7 and was perfectly able to duplicate and display perfectly on my TV with a HDMI connection. After I updated that software to Windows 10 that stopped, so I have now 2 laptops that do not duplicate correctly.

What happens is that the sides are not visible. So half the taskbar, at the top I do not see any tabs, sides also lose some stuff. As I said, I have updated 1 of the 2 laptops already to 10 and I have found out a way to display my vision on the laptop in full, but at the cost of big black lanes around it, so only part of the TV screen is used.

Is there a way to get this fixed? It is such a frustration.

Comment: What graphics cards do your laptops have? You may be able to adjust `overscan` values in the vendor graphics control panel settings; see for eg [How do I enable/disable overscan on my TV in Catalyst Control Center?](http://superuser.com/questions/57239/how-do-i-enable-disable-overscan-on-my-tv-in-catalyst-control-center)

Comment: Have you tried updating the graphics drivers to a version that is Windows 10 compatible, if they exist?

Comment: @bertieb  Thank you for your reaction.  I think I have a intel hd graphics 5500 graphic card

Comment: @DrZoo I did for my old Laptop. However that did not work out for me. That one runs windows 8.1 and is showing the exact same problem.

Comment: I solved it on 1 Laptop. Using this option in the graphics control panel: http://i.imgur.com/aALex0m.png . Allowed me to scale it right as I wanted it. Cheers

Comment: Hi Ben - can you mark your question as answered if you have solved it?  Maybe post the solution as an answer or close the question.