# 1080p LCD not entirely filled up

Tags: hdmi, dvi, gpu, 1080p

I have recently build a new machine with XFX ATi Radeon 5830 for GPU. I have an Asus LCD VH236H monitor which supports 1080p resolution yet when I have it set to the recommended 1080p resolution the screen is not entirely filled up. There is ~1cm (on top and bottom) and ~1.5cm (on right and left side) black frame. I would like to use the LCD's actual size to the fullest but I cannot do it when I use HDMI, unless there is something I am missing. Should I use DVI instead? Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While connected via HDMI and running at your intended resolution, go into the Catalyst Control Center and find Scaling Options under Digital Flat Panel. Move the slider to the right.

If that options screen isn't there, the black borders probably aren't coming from the ATI driver. Instead, try different options in your monitor's on-screen menu.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the CCC and ensure that overscan is set to none. HDMI outputs typically contain overscan to account for old (say rear projection) screens, while DVI does not.

Also see [Kill overscan for ATI drivers?](https://superuser.com/questions/45323/kill-overscan-for-ati-drivers).

I can't seem to find this option on fglrx with a DVI connector though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DVI?  If DVI resolves the problem (which it probably will), then use it instead.  I've found that HDMI doesn't always work as expected.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson - I know that DVI will work fine and since HDMI caries more information over the wire than I actually need so I will just dump it in favour of DVI. But I was wondering if there is a way of making it work.

Comment: @Darius:  You might be able to manually set the resolution, but don't be surprised if these settings get reverted to the one that doesn't fill your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you may need to open your monitors settings, although with new monitors it might be different. Just press the button on the monitor, and usually you can stretch it to fill the empty space.

Comment: This only works with CRT monitors.

Comment: Ah, I do seem to have it on my flatscreen here, but i suppose with new monitors its all different